# How to create a professional horizontal line?

Tags: css

I need to create a horisontal line like this. Can someone add CSS here?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here it is:

```css
body {
  background-color: #830200;
}

hr {
    border: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<hr/>
```

Just use `<hr/>` tag with some styles

Comment: That's it. Thank you!

Comment: Can you make it a bit darker?

Comment: background or the line?

Comment: Done. You can simply tune it by yourself just by changing the last values in `rgba`. It's `0.4` and `0.3` for now